# Rails belongs_to association returns nil in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new with ruby and rails and have been struggling with this issue for a few days. I already searched for an answer but couldn’t find a solution.

I have a many-to-many connection between games, tickers and players by a has_many :through association. The relevant association declarations could look like this:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base        
    has_many :tickers, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :players, :through => :tickers
end

class Ticker < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :games
    belongs_to :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickers, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :games, :through => :tickers
end
```

That means every game has many tickers. Every Ticker has one player. Finally a game with ticker entries can look like this:

> Team 1 vs. Team 2
>
> 00:30 | goal | Player 1
>   01:30 | goal | Player 2 
>   …

I want to show the players name in the games view. This is my app / views / games / show.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Home:</b>
  <%= @game.home_team.team_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Away:</b>
  <%= @game.away_team.team_name %>
</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Activity</th>
    <th>Player</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @tickers.each do |ticker| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= ticker.activity_id %></td>
    <td><%= ticker.players.player_name %></td>
    <td><%= ticker.time %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', ticker %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_ticker_path(ticker) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', ticker, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>     </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Here is my problem:

```
<%= ticker.players.player_name %>
```

gives me the error

> undefined method `player_name' for nil:NilClass

But

```
<%= ticker.player_id %>
```

gives me the right player id. The player with this id exists and has a player_name set. So, this cannot be the reason. But I get nil when calling:

```
<%= ticker.players %>
```

What went wrong? Thank you for help!

Lars

P.S.: Some more information about my code:

The app / controllers / games_controller.rb:

```
  def show
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @tickers = @game.tickers

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @game }
    end
  end
```

My database schema:

```
  create_table "games", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "players", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "player_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "tickers", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "activity_id"
    t.integer "player_id"
    t.integer "time"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer "game_id"
  end
```

This is how I create a new ticker instance (for now):

app / views / games / show.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'New Ticker', new_ticker_path(:game_id=>@game.id) %>
```

app / views / tickers / _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@ticker) do |f| %>
  <% if @ticker.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@ticker.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this ticker from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @ticker.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :game_id, :value => params[:game_id] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :activity_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :activity_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :player_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :player_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :time %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

app / controllers / tickers_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @ticker = Ticker.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @ticker }
    end
  end

  def create
    @ticker = Ticker.new(params[:ticker])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticker.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ticker, notice: 'Ticker was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @ticker, status: :created, location: @ticker }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @ticker.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

belongs_to should be singular. ie

```
belongs_to :game #u have specified 'games'
```

Comment: Yeah. That's it. But could you explain to me, why it is singular and in another case plural?

Comment: because an object can always belong to only 'one' parent rather than many and have 'one or many' children. if u still want the existing code to work then u can add method named 'games' and 'players' in the class and fetch the 'parent' using their id but it wont make sense in the long run.

Comment: I can't upvote. "Vote up requires 15 reputation" - that I don't have - :(